# Detect onclick of any element in a list (android studio)

Tags: android, list, kotlin, android-imagebutton

So I'm working on an app in Android Studio and I'm making a feature where you can set a main image to the image on any button you press.

To check if any item in the list is clicked I'm trying to do something like this (no this isn't actual working code this is just an example of what I'm trying to accomplish):
`images.setOnClickListener(clickedImage: ImageButton) { and then set the main image to the image clicked (main image.srcCompat = clickedImage.srcCompat }`

PS: This is in Kotlin in Android Studio Hedgehog
even more PS: I'm just starting out Kotlin so it might've just been a stupid mistake but I don't know the syntax very good.

What I'm guessing is right (and obviously isn't working) is that to make the list I should do this:

```
val images = listOf( //list containing every single image button available for investment images
        findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.imageButton1),
        findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.imageButton2),
        findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.imageButton3),
        findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.imageButton4),
        findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.imageButton5),
        findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.imageButton6),
        findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.imageButton7),
        findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.imageButton8),
        findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.imageButton9),
        findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.imageButton10),
        findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.imageButton11),
        findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.imageButton12),
        findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.imageButton13),
        findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.imageButton14),
        findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.imageButton15)
    )
```

Anyone know any functions or any way do to this? I'm basically just trying to detect if any button in a list is clicked and then detect which button it is.

Comment: `images.setOnClickListener` there's no way of doing this. but if you have an array or a list, then yes, you could write something that iterates over it to do something, like setting the same listener to all the items in that array or list

Comment: @a_local_nobody thank you for this solution. This seems like it would work completely fine but when I run the program it just doesn't run or it crashes. This is the loop: for (button in images) { button.setOnClickListener { setContentView(R.layout.activity_newinvestment) findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.imageEdit).setImageResource(button.image) } } unfortunately I don't know any way to make code blocks in comments so if there's any way, please tell me so I can make this more readable.

Comment: alright this is the solution and the running is just an issue with gradle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is a for loop. (im an idiot lol)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).